# Независимые id

Tags: html, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/ptHqy/3/

Как сделать чтобы все Title располагались под одним div'ом и стрелки работали нормально?
Спасибо.

Comment: использование нескольких одинаковых id в одном документе нарушает стандарт html, в смысле используйте класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bthsq/2/

Comment: @Олег Б - [можно проще](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/cJ5Rk/2/)

Comment: $div.is(':visible')?'v':'^'  - до такого я пока ещё не дошёл)